# Finding numbers with decimal zeros in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm displaying numbers with decimal zeros like this: 25785  --> 25'785.00

I want to copy & paste this displayed number in the search field and find my actual number.
When I do it my query looks like this `"query": "(25785.00 OR 25785.00*)"`, but the indexed number is `25785` and it doesn't get found.

Can I index this field differently so it'll also find the numbers with the decimal zeros?

---

Mapping:

```
    "my-money" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
            "raw" : {
                "type" : "double"
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matchphrase` query. Details can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html)

Mappings:

```
PUT /mstest
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "money": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Existing data:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "mstest",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "AXlhj0RUNamWTgl090_3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "money": 257851111
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "mstest",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "AXlhjR3f7ALnT2aUN_qN",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "money": 25785
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Search query for number '25785':

```
GET mstest/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "money.raw": "25785.00"
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "mstest",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "AXlhjR3f7ALnT2aUN_qN",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "money": 25785
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

See if this unblocks you.